# How do I systematically identify the dependencies Python has across its accessible package/module tree?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pythonpath

*Question:* How can I systematically probe into files that are involved at any time by the interpreter (like in debug mode).

When everything fails I get error message. What I ask for is the opposite: Everything works, but I don't know how much redundant rubbish I have in comparison to its usage, even though I can imagine that something like pynotify probably could trace it.

*Context:*

I've spent all morning exercising trial & error to get a package to work. I'm sure I have copied the relevant python package into at least 3 directories and messed up my windows `setx -m path` badly with junk. Now I'm wondering how to clean it all up without breaking any dependencies, and *actually learn from the process*.

I can't possibly be the only one wondering about this. Some talented test-developer must have written a script/package that:

```
import everything from everywhere
check for all dependencies
E = list(errorMessages)
L = list_of_stuff_that_was_used
print L
print E
```

so if I have something stored which is not in `L`, I can delete it. But of course the probing has to be thorough to exhaust all accessible files (or at least actively used directories).

What the question is **NOT** about:
I'm not interested in what is on the `sys.path`. This is trivial.

*More Context:*

I know from [The Hitchhikers Guide to Packaging](http://guide.python-distribute.org/) that the future of this problem is being adressed, however it does not probe into the past. So with the transition from Python 2xx to 3xx this problem must become more and more relevant?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dynamic nature of python makes this a next to impossible task.

Functions can import too, for example. Are you going to run all code in all modules?

And then there are backward-compatibility tests; import `pysqlite2` if `sqlite3` is not present, use a backport module if `collections.Counter` isn't present in the current version of Python, etc. There are platform-specific modules (`os.path` is `posixpath`, `ntpath` (same code but renamed) or `riscospath` depending on the current platform), and whole-sale imports into the main module (`posix`, `nt`, `os2`, `ce` and `riscos` all can be used by the `os` module depending on the platform to supply functions).

Packages that use `setuptools` declare their dependencies and are discoverable through the `pkg_resources` library. That's the limit of what you *can* reasonably discover.

Comment: Thanks Martijn; I thought bootstrapping with virtual environment to a temporary directory monitored with pynotify could do the trick(?), but if you think that route is doomed to fail then I wont even try.

Comment: @BHM: Any pip-installable package will declare it's dependencies already, so just use `pkg_resources` and friends for that. Anything you need to install manually, well, you already know it's dependencies then, don't you? :-)